# Callable statement in jdbc

Tags: jdbc, callable-statement

hi i wrote a jdbc program using callable statement and i installed the connector j also .I have created a stored procedure also in mysql .I installed the following driver also

C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21 (3)\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21
but i am still getting an error

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:localhost

java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do you use any development tool? If so which one do you use? For most IDE's jars have to be under `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: i use eclipse in this i added the above mentioned jar file using build path->libraries-->external jar

Comment: If you have put your jars in correct location and still you are getting exceptions, could you post your connection java code? Regards

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this through eclipse then you have to put the mysql required jar file to the lib folder of the project structure or else using build path of the eclipse. If you are doing this local system then you have to set `path(Environmental variable)`.